# Curly brackets with long content cross the margin

Tags: line-breaking, margins

I wonder if there is a way to break a line when it is too long with a curly bracket crossing the margin. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla 
blablabla blablabla blablabla. Here comes a long form, and it
is extremely long. $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.
```

\end{document}

Comment: It's not the curly brackets, but the commas: add `\linebreak[0]` after one of the commas. TeX never breaks a formula at a comma, unless allowed to.